# Upserting nested fields with a dot(.) in key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have query in MongoDB for which I'm trying to upsert an inner nested attribute that contains a dot(.) in the key. E.g. a document might look something like: (below is a fictitious example just to highlight the constraint I'm facing.)

```
const person = {
   name: 'Peter',
   address: {
      'NY.postalCode': 12345,
      'CA.postalCode': 23456,
   }
}
```

However, when I try to update one of the nested attribute in `address` with the below `$set` operation, I get an additional object `NY` under address and its subKey postalCode as a result, instead of the flattened attribute within address.

```
await Person.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
   $set: {
      'address.NY.postalCode': 98765,
   }
}, { new: true });

// Output
{
   name: 'Peter',
   address: {
      'NY.postalCode': 12345,
      'CA.postalCode': 23456,
      NY: {
         postalCode: 98765,
      }
   }
}
```

I've tried using the escape character for dot (\u002e), but get the same output. Also, I have seen some new features for setting fields but only in Mongo v5: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setField/#mongodb-expression-exp.-setField. However, we're using Mongo v4.2 and would not be able to upgrade until a while later.

Would like to check if there are any means to `$set` nested attributes in address that don't completely replace the address object? i.e. to be able to specifically upsert an inner attribute within `address` object?

For example, is it possible to use the aggregation framework to workaround this?
I've tried something like the below, but it didn't work - not sure if its something that I did wrong or its probably not possible to use the aggregation pipeline..

```
Person.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         _id: id,
      },
   },
   {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: {
         $mergeObjects: [
            '$$ROOT.address',
            {
               'NY.postalCode': 98765,
            },
         ],
       } },
   },
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, you need to achieve the update with aggregation pipeline.

1. Use `$literal` to escape the field name with dot.
2. Via `$mergeObjects` to merge current `address` object with `{ NY.postalCode': 98765 }`.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "address": {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$address",
          {
            $literal: {
              "NY.postalCode": 98765
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  new: true
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ytozdz_yTou)